# Importing and using Module

Tags: python, email, python-import

I have a python file that can send emails with a subject, message and recipient. I'd like to import it into another file and use it, but I don't know how I'd do it. The files are in the same folder.

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

def email_alert(subject, body, to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to
    

    user = 'my email address'
    msg['from'] = user
    password = 'my password'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, password)
    server.send_message(msg)

    server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email_alert('Subject', 'message', 'email address')
```

Comment: Just like importing anything else. If this is called `email.py` then in your other script you'd do `import email` and then call the function with `email.email_alert(subject, body, to)`.

Comment: thanks that worked for me. I've never imported my own module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the module's name is `message.py` and it is in the same directory as the script you want to import to: `from message import EmailMessage`

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple! You can just type `import filename` to import `filename.py`. You can add directories to your `PYTHONPATH` and python will look for files there.